# Mostrar resultado automático en PlainText Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Saludos compañeros de StackOverFlow, la consulta es tengo 3 variables a saber:
txtvalor1 y txtvalor2 son EditText los cuales ingreso los datos de numéricos cualquiera y eresult que es una variable de tipo plainText que tiene OBJETIVO OBTENER EL CALCULO NUMÉRICO DE LOS DOS EDITTEXT, ¿se puede lograr esto sin utilizar algún botón?

Bueno tengo este código pero al ingresar datos en el primer textview me cierra la app:

```
package com.example.josue.login;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.text.TextWatcher;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText txt50, txt100, txt200, txt500, txt1000, txt2000, txt5000, txt10000, txt20000, txt50000, txt100000;
    private TextView txtdiezmob;

    public static final String nombres="names";
    TextView txtBienvenido;




  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

      txtBienvenido=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtbienvenido);
      String usuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("names");
      txtBienvenido.setText("¡Bienvenido(a) Hermano(a) "+ usuario + "!");

    txtdiezmob = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtdiezmob);
    txt50 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt50);
    txt100 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt100);
    txt200 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt200);
    txt500 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt500);
    txt1000 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt1000);
    txt2000 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt2000);
    txt5000 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt5000);
    txt10000 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt10000);
    txt20000 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt20000);
    txt50000 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt50000);
    txt100000 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txt100000);


      txt50.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

          @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

              String valor1=txt50.getText().toString();
              String valor2=txt100.getText().toString();
              String valor3=txt200.getText().toString();
              String valor4=txt500.getText().toString();
              String valor5=txt1000.getText().toString();
              String valor6=txt2000.getText().toString();
              String valor7=txt5000.getText().toString();
              String valor8=txt10000.getText().toString();
              String valor9=txt20000.getText().toString();
              String valor10=txt50000.getText().toString();
              String valor11=txt100000.getText().toString();

              int nro1=Integer.parseInt(valor1);
              int nro2=Integer.parseInt(valor2);
              int nro3=Integer.parseInt(valor3);
              int nro4=Integer.parseInt(valor4);
              int nro5=Integer.parseInt(valor5);
              int nro6=Integer.parseInt(valor6);
              int nro7=Integer.parseInt(valor7);
              int nro8=Integer.parseInt(valor8);
              int nro9=Integer.parseInt(valor9);
              int nro10=Integer.parseInt(valor10);
              int nro11=Integer.parseInt(valor11);
              int suma=(nro1*50)+(nro2*100)+(nro3*200)+(nro4*500)+(nro5*1000)+(nro6*2000)+(nro7*5000)+(nro8*10000)+(nro9*20000)+(nro10*50000)+(nro11*100000);
              String resultado=String.valueOf(suma);
              txtdiezmob.setText(resultado);

          }

          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

          }
      });
  }
}
```

Logcat

```
> 04-05 23:49:14.677 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login I/Choreographer:
> Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
> main thread. 04-05 23:49:24.596 1616-1673/system_process W/AudioTrack:
> AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client 04-05 23:49:29.144
> 4257-4269/com.example.josue.login I/art: Background sticky concurrent
> mark sweep GC freed 9647(686KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects,
> 26% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 6.543ms total 49.274ms 04-05 23:49:29.299
> 4257-4283/com.example.josue.login W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib
> not implemented 04-05 23:49:29.300 4257-4283/com.example.josue.login
> W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
> 0xe40c8b80, error=EGL_SUCCESS 04-05 23:49:31.422
> 1616-1673/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied
> by client 04-05 23:49:31.472 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login
> W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input
> event receiver has already been disposed.
>     
>     --------- beginning of system 04-05 23:49:31.797 1616-1981/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already
> focused, ignoring focus gain of:
> com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@353c6ffe
> attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@2b98117c 04-05
> 23:49:34.208 1616-1673/system_process W/AudioTrack:
> AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client 04-05 23:49:43.098
> 4257-4282/com.example.josue.login D/Volley: [248]
> BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ]
> https://xxxxx.xxxx.xxx/inicio.php?user=pily&pwd=1234&role=Tesorero(a)
> 0x7f82ec7b NORMAL 1> [lifetime=8705], [size=118], [rc=200],
> [retryCount=1] 04-05 23:49:43.161 1616-3875/system_process
> I/ActivityManager: START u0
> {cmp=com.example.josue.login/.Main2Activity (has extras)} from uid
> 10064 on display 0 04-05 23:49:43.268
> 4257-4283/com.example.josue.login W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib
> not implemented 04-05 23:49:43.268 4257-4283/com.example.josue.login
> W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
> 0xe40a63a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS 04-05 23:49:43.410
> 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login W/art: Verification of
> java.lang.Object
> com.example.josue.login.Main2Activity.access$super(com.example.josue.login.Main2Activity,
> java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) took 105.179ms 04-05
> 23:49:44.000 1616-1628/system_process I/art: Background sticky
> concurrent mark sweep GC freed 88816(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 3(48KB)
> LOS objects, 26% free, 11MB/16MB, paused 12.477ms total 324.599ms
> 04-05 23:49:45.290 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login I/Choreographer:
> Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
> main thread. 04-05 23:49:45.731 4257-4269/com.example.josue.login
> I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1621(65KB)
> AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 2MB/2MB, paused
> 5.622ms total 98.730ms 04-05 23:49:46.239 4257-4283/com.example.josue.login W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib
> not implemented 04-05 23:49:46.239 4257-4283/com.example.josue.login
> W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
> 0xe40a6500, error=EGL_SUCCESS 04-05 23:49:46.280
> 4257-4269/com.example.josue.login I/art: Background partial concurrent
> mark sweep GC freed 1955(131KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects,
> 39% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 1.636ms total 160.749ms 04-05 23:49:48.289
> 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login I/Choreographer: Skipped 170 frames!
> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 04-05
> 23:49:48.523 1616-1640/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed
> com.example.josue.login/.Main2Activity: +5s343ms 04-05 23:49:52.052
> 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login E/InputEventSender: Exception
> dispatching finished signal. 04-05 23:49:52.052
> 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in
> MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 04-05 23:49:52.054
> 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login E/MessageQueue-JNI:
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>         at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>         at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
>         at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
>         at com.example.josue.login.Main2Activity$1.onTextChanged(Main2Activity.java:51)
>         at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7663)
>         at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7723)
>         at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9440)
>         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:964)
>         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:515)
>         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:454)
>         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
>         at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
>         at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5787)
>         at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5600)
>         at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
>         at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8338)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2306)
>         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1682)
>         at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:130)
>         at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
>         at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:126)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:535)
>         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2533)
>         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
>         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
>         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
>       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.jav
> 04-05 23:49:52.054 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login D/AndroidRuntime:
> Shutting down VM
>     
>     
>     --------- beginning of crash 04-05 23:49:52.055 4257-4257/com.example.josue.login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main
>     Process: com.example.josue.login, PID: 4257
>     java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>         at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>         at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
>         at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
>         at com.example.josue.login.Main2Activity$1.onTextChanged(Main2Activity.java:51)
>         at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7663)
>         at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7723)
>         at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9440)
>         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:964)
>         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:515)
>         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:454)
>         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
>         at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
>         at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5787)
>         at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5600)
>         at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
>         at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8338)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
>         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2306)
>         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1682)
>         at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:130)
>         at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
>         at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:126)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:535)
>         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2533)
>         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
>         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
>         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
>       at android.view.inputmet 04-05 23:49:52.082 1616-3532/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity
> com.example.josue.login/.Main2Activity 04-05 23:49:52.182
> 1616-3527/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version
> 1.4 04-05 23:49:52.507 1616-3527/system_process W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 04-05 23:49:52.507
> 1616-3527/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set
> EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdc23c400, error=EGL_SUCCESS 04-05
> 23:49:53.773 1616-1635/system_process I/Choreographer: Skipped 72
> frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main
> thread. 04-05 23:49:54.333 1616-1635/system_process W/ActivityManager:
> Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{314f435f u0
> com.example.josue.login/.Main2Activity t33 f}
```

Cuando escribo en el editText txt50 se cierra la aplicación.

Comment: Sí, puedes poner un *listener* al último `EditText` (o a los dos, depende), el cual se dispare cuando haya cambios en ellos y haga los cálculos. Investiga sobre eso, en android se usa la interfaz [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) para esos fines. Intenta un código y si tienes fallos entonces plantea aquí tus dudas. Hace falta un intento inicial, partir de algo concreto para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar el LogCat, agrega cual es el mensaje de error que despliega, saludos.

Comment: En el LogCat veo que muestra el siguiente error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "", he intentado varios métodos pero no sé donde radica el problema ya que la app se sigue cerrando al ingresar en el txt50.